# Request/Response using LMS in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, promises, lms

I need a setup in which Component A initiates a data request to Component B through LMS (Publish). Component B, upon subscription to the request, will execute certain logic and subsequently publish the data back to A as a response. However, I prefer this process to occur as a promise, meaning that Component A should wait for Component B to send the response before proceeding. Can someone provide insights on how to implement this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're certain component B is already subscribed and ready to receive messages, you can do something like this:

```
sendMessage(message) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let subscription;
    const callback = (result) => {
      unsubscribe(subscription);
      resolve(result);
    };
    subscription = subscribe(
      this.messageContext,
      COMPONENT_B_EVENT,
      callback
    );
    publish(this.messageContext, COMPONENT_B_EVENT, message);
  });
}
```

Which would then be called as:

```
let result = await this.sendMessage(message);
// do something with result
```

Unfortunately, it's required to subscribe and unsubscribe from within the `Promise` to avoid leaking memory and make sure the function's scope/closure is correct.

---

I typically use a handshake technique to make sure I'm ready. That is, both component A and component B will fire their first message to the channel. Whichever component receives a message first then knows the other component is ready.

```
#partnerAvailable = false;
connectedCallback() {
  this.notifyPartnerAvailable();
}
disconnectedCallback() {
  this.notifyPartnerUnavailable();
}
notifyPartnerAvailable() {
  publish(this.messageContext, CHANNEL_NAME, { available: true, name: this.constructor.name });
}
handlePartnerNotify(message) {
  if(message.name !== this.constructor.name) {
    this.#partnerAvailable = message.available;
  }
}
```

Using this flag, you can determine if the other component is ready to receive a message. You could even make this logic a [mixin or class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/414063/2984) so that it's easy to use across components.